# Using the ContactsContract cursor to get the contacts by group

Tags: android

How would I filter the returned contacts by the `groupName`?

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos,
        long id) {
    String groupName = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos).toString();
    Log.i(this.toString(), String.format("Show Group: %s", groupName));

    Cursor cur = this.getContentResolver().query(
            ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {
        while (cur.moveToNext()) {
            String name = cur
                    .getString(cur
                            .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME));
            if (name != null) {
                Log.i(this.toString(), String.format("Show: %s", name));
            }
        }

        cur.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to filter contacts by group by using the following query:

```
Cursor c = this.managedQuery(Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] {
                    Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Contacts._ID },
                    GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { groupId }, Phone.TIMES_CONTACTED + " DESC");
```

Obviously you need to know the Group Id in order to complete this, how I did this was used a SimpleCursorAdapter to a Spinner w/the following Cursor:

```
Cursor c = managedQuery(Groups.CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[] { Groups.SYSTEM_ID, Groups._ID,},
                        Groups.SYSTEM_ID + " NOT NULL",
                        null, null);
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me for getting all group IDs rather than just system IDs:

```
    public HashMap<String, Long> fillGroupsHashMap(HashMap<String, Long> groups) //
{

    Cursor tempCur = activity.managedQuery(Groups.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] { Groups._ID, Groups.TITLE }, null, null, null);

    tempCur.moveToFirst();
    while (tempCur.moveToNext()) //
    {
        groups.put(tempCur.getString(1), tempCur.getLong(0));
    }
    return groups;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately only System Groups ("groups that have a special meaning to the sync adapter") have SYSTEM_IDs. So this method is not bullet proof.

Answer (score 0):

I had a heachache with this, but finally i get this working with whis code, and now i can filter by only phone numbers and avoid repeated and unused groups:

```
String[] GROUP_PROJECTION = new String[] { 
    ContactsContract.Groups._ID, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE,ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_COUNT ,ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_WITH_PHONES };
    Cursor c = context.getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().query(
                ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_SUMMARY_URI, 
                GROUP_PROJECTION,
                ContactsContract.Groups.SUMMARY_WITH_PHONES +"> 0"  
            , null, ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + " ASC");
```